# Unwraping Dictionary item value

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dictionary and printing dictionary key value as follow :

```
var student = ["name": "Alan Turing",
    "age": "23",
    "gender": "Male"
    ]

println(student["name"])

for item in student{
    println("Student: \(item.0) = \(item.1)" )
}

if let name = student["name"]{
    println(name)    
}
```

The output looks like:

```
Optional("Alan Turing")
Student: gender = Male
Student: age = 23
Student: name = Alan Turing
Alan Turing
```

I wonder why optional value is printed for this line of code

```
println(student["name"]) ==> Optional("Alan Turing")
```

How this is different from `for` and `let` approaches and do I need to explicitly unwrap item value when accessing by key ? e.g

```
println(student["name"]!)
```

[Demo](http://swiftstub.com/574104489/?v=gm)

Comment: for (key, value) in student {
    print("Student: \\(key) = \\(value)" )
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access a dictionary by subscripting it through a key (`dict[key]`) if the key is not present the value returned is `nil`. So the type of the result of `student["name"]` is `String?` to take into account the possibility of being `nil`, and the result is an `Optional(...)`.

In the other two cases instead (`for` and `if let`) the value is automatically unwrapped by the control structure, since it is not possible to have the value `nil` as result, so that the type of `item` is `(String, String)` and not `(String, String?)`, and the type of `name` is `String`.

So, if you use directly `student["name"]` you should unwrap the optional value to get a `String` (by using the different unwrapping operators).

Answer (score 1):

You dictionary definitely has a value for "name" key and you know that, but compiler doesn't know that before it actually goes and checks for it. So when you are doing `println(student["name"])`, compiler isn't sure if it will have value or not, hence considers it optional.

In case of your `for-in` loop approach, compiler first extracts the keys and, hence, it is sure that these keys are present.

And `if-let` automatically unwraps the value if it isn't nil, and hence it can't be optional.